# Netlogo mouseover/mouse hover

Tags: netlogo, mouseover

Is it possible in NetLogo to do a mouseover in a patch so a label appears with the value of a certain patch-variable? I have a case with many patches on screen and need to see a specific value as I pass the mouse over each one of them. I know I can right-click and "inspect patch", but there are so many patches that a mouseover can make the task much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's not a hover option, but you don't have to use `inspect`, you can use some combination of `mouse-down?` and `mouse-xcor`, `mouse-ycor` to get the value to show when you click on a patch (you will need to code it checking where the mouse is, turning on for that patch, turning off on other patches etc).

But it sounds like you may be better with a chooser that has all the different variables, and you can simply select the variable you want to show and have the `label` show that variable's value for all patches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer JenB, this will do.